# Identifying accented chars in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl and I need to identify strings that have the accented characters like umlaut etc. I tried using the regex [A-z], but that doesn't quite work. The perl code snippet I used is:

```
if ($s =~ /^[A-za-z0-9_]+$/ ) {
    # No accented chars, do something
} else {
    accented chars, do something else
}
```

Comment: Might want to check [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) out.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I think it depends on the locale but you could just use `[\x80-\FF]+` if all you have in the extended range is accented characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
if ($s =~ /[^\P{Latin}A-Za-z]/) {
    #  accented chars, do something
} else {
    # No accented chars, do something else
}
```

`\p{Latin}` contains latin letters (including accented letters and characters like `ç œ æ...`). You can negate this class with an uppercase P: `\P{Latin}` *(that contains all characters except latin letters.)*

If you put this in a negated character class: `[^....]` you obtain two negations. So `[^\P{Latin}]` is the same as `\p{Latin}`. But since you have a negated character class you can easily exclude characters you don't want: `[^\P{Latin}A-Za-z]`

Comment: additional followup question: How do I identify non-English characters, whether they are accented or if they are in Hindi?

Comment: @RVS as followup you should to read the [perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) to learn what unicode properties in the codepoints you can match in perl.

Comment: @cajwine, thanks for the URL! I was looking for a simple English/Non-English property, but I cannot find one. We have languages like Gujarati, Greek, but no English. I definitely don't want to match every language to figure out this is in English only. Any ideas?

Comment: p{ASCII} seems to be equivalent to English with no accented chars or umlauts. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @RVS ASCII (regardless of the used language) is ASCII. google for ascii to see what characters are inlcuded. Contains not only letters, but numbers,  `+`, `:` and such symbols and `CTRL-C` and such codes... Strange to see an perl programmer who doesn't know what is the ascii.. ;) ;)

Comment: @cajwine {ASCII} seems to exclude umlauts and other accented chars. That is the question I am trying to ask. Perhaps an expert like you can confirm this or not.

Comment: @RVS i'm an perl **very beginner** yet (unfortunately). But you can check what characters contains the ASCII table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII .

Comment: When in doubt, check the Manual. Start with [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), looking for the \p modifier. This will link you to "Perluniprops", and specifically, [Properties accessible through \p{} and \P{}](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-\p{}-and-\P{}).